# inputFilter в TextInputEditText

Tags: android

Есть у меня в приложении `EditText`.

Этот `EditText` нужен чтобы вводить в него что-то в формате валюты, например: `2.23`, `9.99`

То есть юзер может сначала написать `2` потом `.` потом`23` в этот `EditText`

Добился я такого поведения, реализовав специальный `inputFilter`, который посоветовал Mussa в вопросе https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627148/edittext-with-currency-format. И это действительно работало.

Потом я решил заменить свой `EditText` на вот такую конструкцию:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/secondary_currency"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_currency"
        tools:hint="Болгарский перец">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/secondary_currency_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            tools:text="348929.00" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

И теперь свой `InputFilter` я применяю на  `TextInputEditText`.

И я был удивлен. когда мне не удалось напечатать `.` после`2`, хотя в случае с простым `EditTtext` мог

Почему я не могу напечатать точку в случае с `TextInputEditText`? Как сделать так, чтобы мог?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что у вас стоит `android:inputType="number"`. Если не ошибаюсь, то `number` позволяет вводить только цифры. Точно не помню, но попробуйте `android:inputType="numberDecimal"`.

Все варианты значений видно при вводе строки `inputType`.

Comment: правильно прави